# How can I programmatically execute Route of rejection handler and get resulting HttpEntity?

Tags: scala, spray, akka-http

How can I programmatically execute `Route` of rejection handler and get resulting `HttpEntity` ?

For example assuming that I have `RequestContext` object and `Rejection` object I'd like to execute `RejectionHandler.default` on it and get `HttpEntity`.

Here is example of what I'd like to do:

```
implicit def myRejectionHandler =
  RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
    .handleAll[Rejection] { rejections ⇒

    def prefixEntity(entity: ResponseEntity): ResponseEntity = entity match {
      case HttpEntity.Strict(contentType, data) => {
        import spray.json._
        val text = ErrorResponse(0, "Rejection", data.utf8String).toJson.prettyPrint
        HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, text)
      }
      case _ =>
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected entity type")
    }

    val route: Route = extractRequestContext { ctx =>
      mapResponseEntity(prefixEntity) {
        // Here I want result of `complete` route from RejectionHandler.default
      }
    }
    route
  }
    .handleNotFound {
      complete((NotFound, "Not here!"))
    }
    .result()
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample showing this.  It doesn't have to compile. I just need to understand the code flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get the gist of what you want.  You can just apply the default rejection handler in there where your comment is.  The only thing is that the `apply` there returns an `Option` that will be `None` if the rejections encountered don't hit on anything in that rejection handler.  This is unlikely given that you are using the default handler and it pretty much handles everything, but you still need to account for it in the code (hence my `getOrElse` that results in a generic `InternalServerError`).  The modified code would look like this:

```
val defaultRejectionHandler = RejectionHandler.default

implicit def myRejectionHandler =
  RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
    .handleAll[Rejection] { rejections ⇒

    def prefixEntity(entity: ResponseEntity): ResponseEntity = entity match {
      case HttpEntity.Strict(contentType, data) => {
        import spray.json._
        val text = ErrorResponse(0, "Rejection", data.utf8String).toJson.prettyPrint
        HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, text)
      }
      case _ =>
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected entity type")
    }

    val route: Route = extractRequestContext { ctx =>
      mapResponseEntity(prefixEntity) {
        defaultRejectionHandler.apply(rejections).getOrElse{
          complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)
        }
      }
    }
    route
  }
  .handleNotFound {
    complete((NotFound, "Not here!"))
  }
  .result()
```

This compiles, but I did not actually test it to see if we get the desired effect.  Also, I didn't need the `RequestContext` value `ctx`, so you might be able to remove that `extractRequestContext` layer in there.